# Доказательство корректности алгоритма Куна для нахождения максимального паросочетания

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Много где пишут, что его корректность очевидно следует из теоремы Бержа. Однако не понятно, почему если увеличивающая цепь существует, алгоритм её найдет?

Comment: Вас не затруднит сформулировать теорему и алгоритм? Или хотя бы привести ссылку на формулировку.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, идея вот в чём.

Пусть и правда существует увеличивающая цепь. Поскольку мы перебираем все стартовые вершины, мы в нашем переборе попробуем начать и со стартовой вершины увеличивающей цепи (которая, как мы предположили, существует). Мы перебираем по сути все чередующиеся цепочки (в терминах из текста по ссылке [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)) из этой вершины, так что при переборе мы должны добраться и до той самой существующей цепи.